# How to distinguish CancelBuy from CancelSell instructions in AuctionHouse program

Tags: rust, rpc, auction-house

Auction House has `Cancel` instruction which can cancel both bids and asks.

Which I want to distinguish after getting a transaction with `get_transaction` RPC call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it will change from marketplace to marketplace but you can check on the programs logs.

For Magic Eden cancel bid:

```
const txQuery = await conn.getTransaction('2mQPMTWDuEEJjhM25UubYFtdPUutDTAto9uGwU8AZn59veHTg6nmYC8tpkDZDNxkCCRBVGYXfwQ2Y1zfWYgFK93i', 'confirmed');

let logs = txQuery.meta.logMessages
let isCancelBid = logs.find(a =>{
                if(a.includes("Program log: Instruction: CancelBuy")){
                    return true
                };
```

For Magic Eden cancel listing:

```
const txQuery = await conn.getTransaction('3UCxhkwdz1NhTbTRbkiaJp8Dcy2w8WHdHiJK97bK9biGoPVcZa6mNzXX1QGEwr9LuLw1RJjf5aMJ1F1koLV2GQ5u', 'confirmed');
    
    let logs = txQuery.meta.logMessages
    let isCancelListing = logs.find(a =>{
                    if(a.includes("Program log: Instruction: CancelSell")){
                        return true
                    };
```

Comment: MagicEden did actually split Cancel into two instructions, AH, however, did not.

Answer (score 0):

i think it is about the combination of instructions, (i know you can find cancel instruction all alone buy itself, in this case it is still blurry)
for example:

when the transaction is Cancel Bid you will mostly find "Cancel" instruction followed by "WithdrawFromFee" instrution. and if it is Delisting the combination would be "Cancel" then "CancelListingReceipt".

the logs really help whith that. i recommend using solscan